# Работа с Unity Timeline

Tags: c#, unity3d, timeline

Роюсь в документации юнити, никак не могу найти то что нужно, может кто сталкивался с этим, а если будет кусочек скрипта, будет вообще супер.
Ситуасьйон, необходимо получить список всех signal emitter на треке Timeline в unity, как можно перебором просто получить список этих эмиттеров и время их старта?[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что касается анимационных кривых, кейфреймов с точки зрения кода в основной документации по сути нет. Как прописывать `Tangent` для `Keyframe` можно понять только опытным путем. Одна из самых слабых мест документации.

Но что касается `TimeLine` это отдельное пространство имен и для нее отдельная [документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.timeline@1.0/api/UnityEngine.Timeline.html). Можно заметить, что таймлайн ни о каких `SignalEmitter` не знает, он работает только с абстракцией [IMarker](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.timeline@1.0/api/UnityEngine.Timeline.IMarker.html). У всех кто наследуется от [TrackAsset](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.timeline@1.0/api/UnityEngine.Timeline.TrackAsset.html#UnityEngine_Timeline_TrackAsset) есть метод `IEnumerable<IMarker> GetMarkers()` и другие методы для работы с маркерами. Как можно увидеть на первом скриншоте, с право, тебя интересует второй, а именно `GameObject(`[SignalReceiver](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.timeline@1.0/api/UnityEngine.Timeline.SignalReceiver.html)`)`.

> ### Class SignalReceiver
>
> Listens for emitted signals and reacts depending on its defined reactions

[SignalEmitter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.timeline@1.0/api/UnityEngine.Timeline.SignalEmitter.html) так-же `IMarker`.

Comment: Не в той документации копал, спасибо большое, добрый человек)

Comment: Сам задаюсь вопросом нахрена этим злым человекам разные документации для каждого пекеджа, даже того который в коробке, как `UnityEngine.UI`, который в основной документации есть и `UnityEditor` который вообще в другом пространстве имен... где логика?